Add github branch name to specifier in Jenkins
I am setting up a Jenkins pipeline which gets triggered when I push a commit.
I am using Git SCM for this purpose where I am having to hardcode the name of the branch
in the field Branch Specifier (blank for 'any').
How do I make the entry generic as the push can come from any branch. I tried leaving it blank but when I build the pipeline, it defaults to some branch which does not have the file and the build fails.

I find these two statements contradictory: "the push can come from any branch" and "some branch which does not have the file". So do you want to trigger from any branch, even those that don't have the file?
